# How to store images from firebase using glide library for offline use?

Tags: android, firebase, android-glide, okhttp

I want to get images from firebase database to store them in offline mode using Glide library.

- I made the class that is named as my app and I put the code for
  enabling firebase sync. (keeping(true))
- Issue: is it mandatory to use Libraries like: "Volley, okhttp3" or
  any library except (glide) to make this app works fine and store the 
  images for offline use?

Comment: Hi , you can achieve this functionality by Using Glide/Picasso any library , check my answer below

Answer (score 2):

> "Its called **ImageCaching**."
>
> To achieve this We can use `NetworkPolicy` , so first its going and
>   checking in `cache` if not its going in `onError` , there its `downloading`
>   the `image` from URL.

**Caching Using Picasso**

```
Picasso.get().load(YOUR_IMAGE_URL_HERE).resize(100, 100).centerCrop().
                        networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE).into(yourImageView, new Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Exception e) {
                        Picasso.get().load(YOUR_IMAGE_URL_HERE).resize(100, 100).centerCrop().
                                into(yourImageView);
                    }
                });
```

**Caching Using Glide**

```
 Glide.with(MainActivity.this)
       .load(YOUR_IMAGE_URL_HERE)
       .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE)
       .into(yourImageView);
```

Here is one of my full sample code - https://github.com/myJarvis/MoviesWorld-OfflineOnlineSupport

Comment: You shouldn't retry requesting if is an error.

Comment: I have added NetworkPolicy , first its going and checking in cache if not its going in onError , there its downloading the image from URL.

Kindly check the question

Comment: Now is better .

Comment: thanks @FlorescuCătălin , feel free to upvote :)

Comment: Thanks bro.. you saved me !! ..

Comment: its alright , Please accept this answer by clicking on the tic button in left side of answer